# Conditional switching to mobile version of web site

Tags: javascript

I have a web site containing millions of photos from thousands of events over the last 26 years, and the directory structure is \root\events\(year)\(eventdate) so that all the photos and files for any given event date are kept together. Each directory has its own index.shtml file which sorts out the organisation of the content.

I want to add a mobile version of the site. My current thinking is to add a mobile.shtml page to each directory, and switch based on a simple screen width test. All the pages throughout the site use a common header include, so I need to add code to a common header, but which will only switch if the current page is the index.shtml file. I´ve used the following, and it fails to switch.

This is what I´ve added to the include file

......

```
<body>
<script>
var url = location.href;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var a = "index.shtml";
if((screen.width < 600) && (filename.equals(a))) {
    location.href = 'mobile.shtml';
}
</script>
```

.........

I´m not a JS programmer and am trying to implement code seen hereabouts, so would appreciate learning why this fails! Thanks in advance to anyone that replies.

Comment: A properly-designed site doesn't need a "mobile version". This is 2014, we have media queries, use them!

Comment: Try to avoid mobile redirects. They are universally loathed and not necessary on most instances. Check out CSS [Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Accept both the above comments, but this is a site that has grown and been in existence since 1997! Ideally it would have a total redesign, but the content per folder is totally inconsistent. Hence the reason why I was looking at adding the redirect and putting at a minimum a welcome page for each event that is mobile friendly.

Comment: That's not how you declare a string in javascript. Try using 'var'; i.e. var url = location.href;

Comment: Thanks John_C. I´ve updated the code, and added a missing semi colon, but the code still doesn´t do the switch. I´ve edited the post above to show the current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used this for a while but I am pretty sure it still works. Place this in the Head of your HTML e.g. desktop website - index.html

```
<!-- Detect and redirect for mobile -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iP(od|hone)/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)){
            if(document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false")==-1) {
                window.location.href="http://myWebsite.com/index_mobile.html";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Be sure to add your correct redirect here in this line from above:

```
window.location.href="http://myWebsite.com/index_mobile.html";
```

---

As a second solution to support your original intentions, I managed to get a variation of your JS code working live here [DEMO](http://www.totallytotallyamazing.com/jsFiddle/index.shtml). My DEMO will take you to GitHub if you view it from a screen with a width < or = to 600px. To test it properly you must view it from monitor sizes above and below 600px widths. Below is my variation of your JS code:

```
<body>
<script>
    var url = window.location.href;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var a = 'index.shtml';
    if((screen.width <= 600) && (filename == a)) {
        window.location.href = 'https://github.com/';
    }
</script>
```

*** NOTE the difference that my code will redirect you to GitHub as opposed to 'mobile.shtml'**

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. The switch to the mobile site needs to happen *only* if the current page is index.shtml because this is used in a common include file. The switch code I´ve used above works if it simply checks the screen width, but I need it to switch if the device is mobile AND the current page is index.shtml because the code is similar in over 2000 sub directories. It needs to ignore the switch for all other pages in the directory. Cheers. Ray

Comment: Glad to help! Maybe I am not understanding completely but couldn't you just add your "mobile.shtml" to the redirect of my code snippet and place all of that into the head of your "index.shtml" file?

Comment: Sure. The code is in an include file, that is used in every html file throughout the whole site. There are over 2000 directories in the site, averaging 90 event sub directories in each of the 26 years. Apart from the index.shtml file, there are other html files, that also use the same include file. So I want the switch to identify the current page as "index.shtml" and switch to mobile.shtml. If the current page is say "page1.shtml" then it should stay on page1.shtml and not do the switch. I just can´t understand why the second condition is a permanent false and the switch doesn´t happen.

Comment: @rbs_gb Please see my newest solution above which more closely supports your original intentions.

Comment: Thank you! As I mentioned, I´m not a JS programmer, but I had read that using == for string comparisons had a number of pitfalls, and therefore .equals was the better syntax. For whatever reason, your syntax works! I´m not allowed to vote up your solution, but would if I could! Thanks again!

Comment: No Problem glad to help! Just please remember and come back to vote me up when you can at 15 or more points.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish should be done with responsive design techniques. In a perfect world, you could just use [media queries](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/)

to adjust the css applied to format the content differently.

But I have also had the need sometimes to do server side detection of the client, because I would render an entirely different widget based on the form factor. You seem to be using .shtml, which is a poor choice IMHO. Your webserver at a min must support php, and that is a way more powerful server side choice for your app. PhpMobileDetect is a great script that will give you a way to detect if it is mobile, tablet, or desk. Problem now is that we have enormous phones, or phablets. But it might just be the right fit for your task.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. No question that if the site was being done from a 2014 perspective, it would be done differently. There is a huge legacy content in the site, and it works for a desktop environment. It uses simple server side includes at the moment, with common header and footer sections. I did think of simply putting a wrapper div in the header/footer, and making the desktop layout invisible via the media queries, with a new div for the mobile section, made visible through CSS and media queries.

Comment: Sadly, it still doesn´t get me round the need to do it only for the index.shtml files and to leave the other pages untouched. On average, each sub directory has around 10 other shtml files, and the thought of rewriting around 20000 pages is just a non starter. I fully accept what I´m doing is a kludge, but life isn't perfect!